# Multi Class Classification of Text

Tags: machine-learning, classification, modeling, text-mining, multi-class

I am trying to develop a model that classifies text documents to ~50 classes. Would appreciate any help regarding what should my approach be to make it happen?

I have a training set of ~5000 documents. My initial approach is to use a random forest on the term document matrix -

Few questions/challenges:

1. The matrix is really sparse
2. How to finally define accuracy
3. should I create binary flags for each class and develop multiple models for each class?
4. Should I do a K-Means clustering on the data prior to the RF and
   then run RF in each cluster to improve accuracy?

Any help is really appreciated.